# Regex how to check last 4 numbers from long number

Tags: python, regex

I would like to check only last 4 digit number with python
for example, if I have following numbers and I want to check last four number whether it start from 10 
or 02

1. 201600001057 ( I want to get 1057)
2. 201600000216 ( I want to get 0216)

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not a task for regular expressions. That's a task for the modulo operator. Divide by 1000, the modulus will give you the last four digits.

Comment: this can be done with regexs, especially if the application is a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you use regex for this?

```
last4 = str(number)[-4:]
if last4.startswith(('10', '02')):
    print("yes, actually")
```

Comment: Ignore my last comment(I missed the second slicing ;-)), but I'd suggest `str.startswith` over slicing: `last4.startswith(('10', '02'))`

Comment: you are getting the substring before the last 4 chars, your slice should be [-4:]

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=(?:10|02))\d{4}$
```

This should do it.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kP4pZ2/18

```
print re.findall(r"(?=(?:10|02))\d{4}$",x,re.M)
```

x is your string.

Comment: `I want to check last four number whether it start from 10 or 02`

Answer (score 1):

You could use re.search or re.match. It would match the strings only if the last four numbers starts with `10` or `02`

```
>>> s = "201600001057"
>>> s1 = "201600000216"
>>> re.search(r'(?:10|02)\d{2}$', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fdbb2b6d3d8>
>>> re.search(r'(?:10|02)\d{2}$', s).group()
'1057'
>>> re.search(r'(?:10|02)\d{2}$', s1).group()
'0216'
>>> if re.search(r'(?:10|02)\d{2}$', s1):
...     print 'Matches'
... 
Matches
>>> if re.search(r'(?:10|02)\d{2}$', s):
...     print 'Matches'
... 
Matches
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without regexp

```
>>> s="201600001057"
>>> s[-4:]
"1057"
>>> s[-4:].isdigit()
True
>>> s="201600001057a"
>>> s[-4:].isdigit()
False
```

Answer (score 0):

the `findall` function in re module can be used

```
>>> import re
>>> x="201600001057"
>>> re.findall('\d{4}$', x)
['1057']
```